# Running Shell Script from CPP , while Script bundled inside the exe

Tags: c++, shell, makefile

I wanna create a exe which has the Shell Script and Simple CPP file which calls the Shell Script using `system()` function. Lets say exe name 'myInstaller'  which has files myintsaller.cpp and myShell.sh. When i run the exe myInstaller , it must execute shell script. I want to do like this so i can protect my Shell Script code ,which has over 3000 lines of Code.

How do i do this ... I m in real need of this.

Comment: google around for shell compilers (there are a few, and the purpose is to protect shell code from prying eyes). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i've searched, there is no way to bundle the script inside the exe. Either it would be Shell Compiler as shelter suggested or plain shell scripts. No work around for this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's Windows platform since you speak about `exe`. In this case you can add your script as a resource to your exe, extract it in run-time and execute.

Comment: NO , i m talking about linux. Remember i m using Shell Script , and i don't want to extract it. If i extract it, user will be able to see my code

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the script as a string in your C++ code and call `system("sh -c '" + code + "'")`. Quoting may be an issue though. Otherwise, write it to a temp location, execute it and then unlink it.

Comment: You meant to add 3000 lines of Script to a CPP as a String ..? That won't be quite good i hope.